# "More Views" images are 66x66, containers for said images are 60x60, how to fix?

Tags: magento-community

On our website, we have several products where their secondary images are displaying chopped off on the bottom and right sides of the image. More specifically, the images generated by Magento are 66px square, and the parent `li` is 60px square. We need to make these numbers match to make the full thumbnail be shown, but I just don't know how to do it. I guess I have a few questions:

- What is used for Magento's image generation?
- What can be done to change how Magento generates the thumbnail images below the primary image?
- Does anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple.

Just go to `app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`

and inside the gallery loop

`<?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>`

there is a method that resizes the images, and should look like this

`<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(56); ?>`

Obviously you can change the size inside the resize method, and don't forget to also update the width and height attributes in the `<img>` tag

Answer (score 0):

used  `keepFrame(false)` to resize function for remove space

```
  <?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')
->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(66)->keepFrame(false); ?>
```

more details  on

http://www.atwix.com/magento/how-to-resize-images/

inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/properly-remove-white-image-frame-upon-resizing-photos-in-magento/